# POSIXct returning NA

Tags: r

My dataframe has this structure:

```
 str(marc)
 $ Data   : Date, format: "2015-10-31" "2015-10-31" "2015-10-31" ...
 $ Hora   :Class 'times'  atomic [1:351] 0.792 0.792 0.792 0.792 0.5 ...
 .. ..- attr(*, "format")= chr "h:m:s"
```

I am trying to create a new column joining Data and Hora:

```
marc$Timestamp=as.POSIXct(paste(marc$Data, marc$Hora), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

But as.POSIXct is returning NAs.

```
$ Timestamp: POSIXct, format: NA NA NA ...
```

I used the same process to create a Timestamp with other dataframe and it have worked. What I am doing wrong this time?
Thank you very much!

```
> dput(marc$Hora)
structure(c(0.791666666666667, 0.791666666666667, 0.791666666666667, 
0.791666666666667, 0.5, 0.833333333333333, 0.833333333333333, 
0.833333333333333, 0.708333333333333, 0.833333333333333, 0.708333333333333, 
0.708333333333333, 0.604166666666667, 0.604166666666667, 0.604166666666667, 
0.708333333333333, 0.8125, 0.75, 0.541666666666667, 0.75, 0.541666666666667, 
0.541666666666667, 0.541666666666667, 0.8125, 0.8125, 0.520833333333333, 
0.8125, 0.8875, 0.9375, 0.9375, 0.9375, 0.8875, 0.895833333333333, 
...
 format = "h:m:s", class = "times")
```

Before use POSIXct, I ran:

```
marc$Hora=times(marc$Hora)
```

Hora should be H:M:S, but it didn't change

Comment: The `Hora` is different `class`.  It is not in the `HMS` format.  can you post a small example with `dput` by editing the post.  Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483629/how-convert-decimal-to-posix-time

Comment: Thanks @akrun! I edited my post. I think it is some problem with time format!

Comment: Your dput is not full, but I copied the ones you posted.  Did you used any particular library to create this.  I am not getting any NA `as.POSIXct(paste(Sys.Date(), v1))[1:5]
[1] "2018-11-03 19:00:00 EDT" "2018-11-03 19:00:00 EDT" "2018-11-03 19:00:00 EDT" "2018-11-03 19:00:00 EDT"
[5] "2018-11-03 12:00:00 EDT"`.  In my case, I don't have the decimals.  It is in the format `v1[1:5]#
[1] 19:00:00 19:00:00 19:00:00 19:00:00 12:00:00`

Comment: I would use `dput(head(matc$Hora))` for a small example

Comment: Yes, @akrun. I imported a Excel file about 8000000 rows. It is the reason my dput is not full.

Comment: As I said `dput(head(matc$Hora))` subsets the data and get the structure for those.  `dput` gives the exact structure you have for others to test it.  An incomplete dput will limit that and others will lose some attributes in the structure.  BTW, what package you used other than `base R`

Comment: > dput(head(marc$Hora))
     structure(c(0.791666666666667, 0.791666666666667, 0.791666666666667, 
0.791666666666667, 0.5, 0.833333333333333), format = "h:m:s", class = "times")
Sorry if is a stupid question. I am starting to use R. I imported my data using read.xlsx and used function "times" from Chron trying to make time (Hora) in H:M:S, but it remained as a decimal

Comment: If I assign your dput to `v1` `v1#
[1] 19:00:00 19:00:00 19:00:00 19:00:00 12:00:00 20:00:00`  Are you getting this format? and converting it to numeric gives `as.numeric(v1)#
[1] 0.7916667 0.7916667 0.7916667 0.7916667 0.5000000 0.8333333`

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue `as.POSIXct(paste(Sys.Date(), v1))#
[1] "2018-11-03 19:00:00 EDT" "2018-11-03 19:00:00 EDT" "2018-11-03 19:00:00 EDT" "2018-11-03 19:00:00 EDT"
[5] "2018-11-03 12:00:00 EDT" "2018-11-03 20:00:00 EDT"`

Comment: It's very strange. I do not have HMS format. I also tryed to assign my dput to V1 and had [1] 0.7916667 0.7916667 0.7916667 0.7916667 0.5000000 0.8333333. 
If I use times(v1), it returns [1] 19:00:00 19:00:00 19:00:00 19:00:00 12:00:00 20:00:00. But if I use times in my dataframe marc$Hora, it is still decimal and doesn't change to hms.

Comment: @akrun, thank you very much for spend you time helping! I found that was a problem with Hora in the 247th row. Now it was fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I thought I recognized that class and format as coming from package `chron` (not "Chron"):

```
library(chron)
 Hora

# [1] 19:00:00 19:00:00 19:00:00 19:00:00 12:00:00 20:00:00 20:00:00 20:00:00 17:00:00
#[10] 20:00:00 17:00:00 17:00:00 14:30:00 14:30:00 14:30:00 17:00:00 19:30:00 18:00:00
#[19] 13:00:00 18:00:00 13:00:00 13:00:00 13:00:00 19:30:00 19:30:00 12:30:00 19:30:00
#[28] 21:18:00 22:30:00 22:30:00 22:30:00 21:18:00 21:30:00
```

So they are values that are at the hour boundaries. If you build an example using the `str` information with that`knowledge:

```
 marc <- data.frame( Data =as.Date("2015-10-31", "2015-10-31", "2015-10-31"),
 Hora=structure(c( 0.792, 0.792, 0.792),format = "h:m:s", class = "times"))
 marc
#----------------
        Data     Hora
1 2018-11-03 19:00:29
2 2018-11-03 19:00:29
3 2018-11-03 19:00:29
```

The seconds are off a bit by virtue of rounding. At any rate you should coerce the `Hora` values to character before `paste`-ing:

```
as.POSIXct( paste(marc$Data,  as.character(marc$Hora) ) )
#[1] "2018-11-03 19:00:29 PDT" "2018-11-03 19:00:29 PDT" "2018-11-03 19:00:29 PDT"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @42-, but there was a problem with my raw data, on the 247th row. Because of this, all the functions worked with the vector I provided, but not in my dataframe. Now it was fixed.