# Repeating x axis R

Tags: r

I have data with the amount of radiation at a specific time (hour, minutes) for three repeating days. I want to plot this so the x-axis goes from 0 - 24 3 times. So the x axis repeats itself. And on the y axis the amount of radiation. I have tried the following script without any succes.

```
plot(gegevens[,1],gegevens[,2],type='l',col='red',xaxt='n',yaxt='n',xlab='',ylab='')

axis(1, at=(0:74),labels = rep.int(0:24,3), las=2)

mtext('Zonnetijd (u)', side=1,line=3)
```

The dataset was to big so I've selected the first two hours from 2 days. The first column is the time en the second is the radiation. The data then looks as followed:

```
structure(c(0, 0.083333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 0.25, 0.333333333333333, 
0.416666666666667, 0.5, 0.583333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 
0.75, 0.833333333333333, 0.916666666666667, 1, 1.08333333333333, 
1.16666666666667, 1.25, 1.33333333333333, 1.41666666666667, 1.5, 
1.58333333333333, 1.66666666666667, 1.75, 1.83333333333333, 1.91666666666667, 
0.0158590638878904, 0.0991923972212234, 0.182525730554557, 0.26585906388789, 
0.349192397221223, 0.432525730554557, 0.51585906388789, 0.599192397221223, 
0.682525730554557, 0.76585906388789, 0.849192397221223, 0.932525730554557, 
1.01585906388789, 1.09919239722122, 1.18252573055456, 1.26585906388789, 
1.34919239722122, 1.43252573055456, 1.51585906388789, 1.59919239722122, 
1.68252573055456, 1.76585906388789, 1.84919239722122, 1.93252573055456, 
0.066, 0.066, 0.068, 0.068, 0.068, 0.066, 0.066, 0.066, 0.066, 
0.066, 0.066, 0.066, 0.057, 0, 0, 0, -0.002, 0, 0, -0.002, 0, 
-0.002, -0.009, -0.011, 0, -0.002, 0, -0.002, 0, -0.002, 0, 0.002, 
0, 0, 0, 0, -0.002, -0.002, -0.007, 0, -0.002, 0, 0, 0, -0.002, 
-0.002, -0.002, 0), .Dim = c(48L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    c("t", "z")))
```

Comment: Data (and code) posted as images is a really bad idea, it forces us to type it if we want to have a test dataset. Can you post sample data in the much better `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(gegevens)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(gegevens, 20))`.

Comment: Your approach seems to be good, but maybe has problems due to your data format? Like, what is the range of the first column? Can you share a little sample data in a reproducible format? (Your image shows some stuff, but it doesn't make it easy to import into R, or see what's going on.) `dput()` is a great way to share a copy/pasteable version of an R object.

Comment: Thanks for the `dput` - this clears up a lot. Is there anything in the data to indicate which row belongs to which day? Or just the order of the rows - when the first column goes back to 0 that is the start of the next day?

Comment: row 1-24 are from day 1 and row 25-48 are from day 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marc has good advice about using a datetime class. Overall, that is a good way to go. [See this question for examples of converting decimal times in hours to `POSIX` datetime class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14483629/903061).

If you want to continue with your numeric data we the data itself to indicate what day it occurs on. Here we create a new column identical to the first, but adding `24` every time the first column has a negative difference between successive rows:

```
gegevens = cbind(gegevens, gegevens[, 1] + 24 * c(0, cumsum(diff(gegevens[, 1]) < 0)))
```

Now when we plot using our new column, the hours are correctly spaced by day:

```
plot(gegevens[, 3], gegevens[, 2], type = 'l', col = 'red', xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n', xlab = '', ylab = '')
```

You have some axis issues as well. There is no `24` hour, we usually call this the `0` hour. And `24 * 3 = 72`, not `74`, so  our maximum hour (starting at `0`) is `71`:

```
axis(1, at= 0:71, labels = rep.int(0:23,3), las = 2)
```

Here is the resulting plot on your sample data. It should "work" on your full data, but I agree with Marc that it is probably too  many labels. Using a `POSIXct` date-time format is the best way to flexibly make adjustments.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you would be better off to move towards a date/time class for your axis. Then you can have more control on what to plot etc. Below is an example:

```
# create example data
df <- data.frame(
  T = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2000-01-01 00:00:00"), 
    by = "hours", length.out = 24*3)
)
df
df$St <- cumsum(rnorm(24*3))

# plot
png("test.png", width = 8, height = 4, units = "in", res = 200)
op <- par(mar = c(4,4,1,1), ps = 8)
plot(St ~ T, df, type="l",col='red',xaxt='n',yaxt='n',xlab='',ylab='')
axis(1, at=df$T, labels = format(df$T, "%H"), las=2)
mtext('Zonnetijd (u)', side=1,line=3)
par(op)
dev.off()
```

[image]

You Can see that you may have some space issues with the labels when you plot every one.

Here is another example with 3-hour increment labels:

```
# alt plot
AT <- seq(min(df$T), max(df$T), by = "3 hour") # 3 hour increments
LAB <- format(AT, "%H")
png("test2.png", width = 8, height = 4, units = "in", res = 200)
op <- par(mar = c(4,4,1,1), ps = 8)
plot(St ~ T, df, type="l",col='red', xlab='', ylab='', xaxt='n')
axis(1, at = AT, labels = LAB, las=2)
mtext('Zonnetijd (u)', side=2, line=3)
mtext('hour', side=1, line=3)
par(op)
dev.off()
```

[image]